# ¿Es necesario el uso de 'volatile' en estas dos variables de instancia? (Algoritmo de la Panadería)

Tags: java, hilos, algoritmos, proceso

Soy estudiante de Informática, y ahora mismo me encuentro estudiando una asignatura sobre Concurrencia.
Mi duda viene cuando en un código de ejemplo acerca de una explicación sobre el uso de **Exclusión mutua** con más de dos hebras mediante el **Algoritmo de la Panadería**, veo que las variables de instancia de la clase Panadería no llevan la palabra clave *volatile*, lo que a mi entender quiere decir que cada una de las hebras podría tener su propia copia de esta variable, y no utilizar una en común para todas, lo que creo que podría llevar a un error en la ejecución del código.
Es por esto que quería preguntar si se trata de un error en el código de ejemplo, o simplemente se me pasa algún dato que no tengo en cuenta.

**Clase Panadería.**

```
public class Panaderia {
  private int[] turno;
  private boolean[] pidiendoTurno;
  
  public Panaderia(int N){
    turno = new int[N];
    pidiendoTurno = new boolean[N];
  }

  public void cogeTurno(int id){
    pidiendoTurno[id] = true;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<turno.length; i++)
      if (max<turno[i]) max=turno[i];
    turno[id] = max + 1;
    pidiendoTurno[id] = false;
  }

  private boolean meToca(int id,int i){
    if (turno[i] > 0 && turno[i] < turno[id])
      return false;
    else if (turno[i] == turno[id] && i < id)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  public void esperoTurno(int id){
    for (int i = 0; i<turno.length; i++){
      while (pidiendoTurno[i])Thread.yield();
      while (!meToca(id,i)) Thread.yield();
    }
  }

  public void salePanaderia(int id){
    turno[id] = 0;
  }
}
```

**Clase Cliente.**

```
class Cliente extends Thread{
  private int id;
  private Panaderia pan;
  
  public Cliente(int id,Panaderia pan){
    this.id = id; this.pan = pan;
  }

  public void run(){
    pan.cogeTurno(id);
    pan.esperaTurno(id);
    // el cliente id es atendido por el dependiente
    pan.salePanaderia(id);
    // el cliente id sale de la panadería
  }
}
```

En resumen, mi pregunta es si las variables de instancia de la clase Panadería, *turno* y *pidiendoTurno* deberían ser volátiles o son correctas así como están.

Eso es todo, muchísimas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: El `volatile` se lo usa cuando un hilo cambia el valor de una variable compartida, por ende, ese valor será visible para los otros hilos que intenten acceder a dicha variable. En tu caso dependerá de la situación, si tienes un hilo `A` que cambia el contenido de la variable `turno` y sí tienes otros hilos que leen esa misma variable, entonces ahí necesitas usar el `volatile`, de lo contrario, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una buena pregunta... y la respuesta es que no es necesario en este caso. Veamos el porqué:

De la documentación de Oracle [leemos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html#V):

> <sup>*volatile*</sup> (...) keyword used in variable declarations that specifies that the variable is modified asynchronously by concurrently running threads.

*... palabra reservada usada en la declaración de variables que especifica que la variable es modificada asíncronamente por hilos concurrentes.*

Esto significa que si modificas la variable, te conviene que ésta sea `volatile`. Pero en tu código las variables ¡no se modifican! Es decir, nunca se asigna un nuevo valor, un **nuevo array**, a las variables `turno` o `pidiendoTurno`. Es el array ya asignado el que recibe cambios, pero el objeto es **siempre el mismo**.